# How can I increase the grid floor line thickness for major (or minor) divisions?

Tags: 3d-view

Running Blender 2.81: I can't find a way to increase the width of the grid floor lines (major or minor subdivisions). I found the theme setting for the grid color, and the contrast seems to automatically adjust based on zoom level, but overall on my 4k monitor it's difficult to discern the major grid subdivisions. For example, with the default 10, this is what I see:

[image: Major grid lines barely visible]

Adding more details from a comment below, when I modify the resolution scale and the "line width" in the interface options, it seems to actually make the major/minor grid lines disappear more:

[image: Major grid lines nearly invisible after scale]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the grid thickness in the *Viewport Overlay* drop-down menu.

[image]

Comment: I belive the *Scale* slider only zooms in on the grid, it doesn't actually change the line thickness :). Have a +1 anyway.

Comment: Ah whoops, misread the question :/

Comment: Yeah... this only scales the grid.. just got to testing it out...